# How to make the GridView adapt to different resolutions in Windows Store apps?

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I know when the resolution is changed, `GridView` grows. But I don't want that. I have `GridView` and it has fixed `GridViewItem` that's 9. So when the resolution is change the `GridViewItem` should be bigger. I want to use `GridView` as it has selection behaviour. Please guide me for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put everything in a `Viewbox` and it will scale with the screen pixel resolution.